# Vuex : token doesn't stored in local storage

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, state, vuex

I have this store in Vue App using vuex :

```vue
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    email: null,
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || null,
    role: null
  },
  mutations: {
    saveToken (state, token) {
      state.token = token
    }
  },
  actions: {
    createToken (context, user) {
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/user/login', {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }).then(response => {
        const token = response.data.token
        localStorage.setItem('token', token)
        context.commit('saveToken', token)
      })
    }
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

When I login the token state is changed correctly, but when I refresh the page the state is null again.

Comment: Inspect your devtools to see if you actually have any successful token set: `chrome dev tools > application > storage > local storage` should help you see if the token is here. Never tried to have something _dynamic_ in the state, maybe it's not feasable or it needs a `window` prefix. If it's not working in the state, a getter could help.

Comment: I am using vue dev tool ,I will try getters

Comment: I'd recommend still checking if you have a local storage token here, before proceeding any further.

Comment: I checked it restart the chrome the localstorage is saved

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to set the axios headers authorization

```
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
```

The above is if you are using Bearer auth.

Secondly, make sure if backend sends in login a refresh token because you need also that to save in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `npm install --save vuex-persistedstate@3.2.1`